# {{HTML::image}} set width and height in Laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-4

Sorry for the stupid question, but I looked everywhere in the doc. If I want to set size, height and width of an image with `HTML::image`, how can I do it?
I tried with:

```php
{{ HTML::image('path', array('width' => 70 , 'height' => 70)); }}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It should work with

```
{{ HTML::image('path', 'alt', array( 'width' => 70, 'height' => 70 )) }}
```

The alt text comes before the attributes array.

Comment: That's correct, from the api... string image(string $url, string $alt = null, array $attributes = array(), bool $secure = null)
Generate an HTML image element.

Comment: sorry, i didn't know that alt couldn't be null

Comment: alt can be null, but attributes still has to be the 3rd parameter. So if you dont want to specify alt (you should always), you can write `HTML::image('path',null,$attr)`.

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 5 following ways to use img in blade:

```
{!! HTML::image('img/picture.jpg', 'a picture', array('class' => 'thumb')) !!}
```

**Note: you need to install laravel library before use HTM i.e "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",**

OR

```
<img src="{!!asset('img/picture.jpg')!!}">
```

OR

Set dynamically url:

```
<img src="{!!asset('img/').'/'.$imgsrc!!}">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** : store image path to your MYSQL table field. And dont forget the dot ( **.** ) at the beginning of **filepath**.

```html
<img src='./images/bajja_huggy2.gif' class= img-responsive style= height: 22px; width: 100px; >
```

you can see how I have used twitter bootstrap and other properties.

```html
@foreach($imagefiles as $img)
<div class="col-xs-2 ">
  {{ $img->image_3}}
</div> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

```
{{ HTML::image($product->image, $product->title, array('width' => '90%', 'height' => '50%')) }}
```

it required to be Apostrophe if create inside the percent.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="{{ asset('folder-name/pic_trulli.jpg')}}" class="img-fluid" style="min-width: 20px; min-height: 20px;">
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<img src='./images/bajja_huggy2.gif' class= img-responsive style= height: 22px; width: 100px; >
```

Comment: The OP expected an answer that uses Laravel code. Although yours is correct, it doesn't use Laravel. Besides this excerpt is an exact copy of is an exact copy of [user2592890](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28763765/908174)'s answer.